# jQuery Select Nested List - target same level list item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

First time posting, so forgive me if not formatting great.

Long story short, but I'm creating an accordion feature. As each item is selected it disables the option selected and then disables the other anchor tags within the unordered list and that is surrounded by a div.

The issue I have, is that I want to have a nest list as per the sample below. When I click the option primary level list item, I want to disable only the same level list items. And NOT the nested list below it.

Have tried a bunch of different setting trying to get it to target that level only.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

```
<div id="q2">
            <ul class="primary">
            <p class="question">Question 2.</p>
            <li>
                <a class="toggle notselected" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 3</a>
                <div class="inner" id="q2-1">
                  <ul class="secondary">
                      <li>
                          <a href="#" class="toggle notselected">Open Inner #1</a>
                          <div class="inner">
                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
                              </p>
                          </div>
                      </li>

                      <li>
                          <a href="#" class="toggle notselected">Open Inner #2</a>
                          <div class="inner">
                              <p>
                                  Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
                              </p>
                          </div>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="toggle notselected" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 4</a>
                <div class="inner" id="q2-2">
                  <ul>
                      <li>
                          <a href="#" class="toggle notselected">Technically any number of nested elements</a>
                          <ul class="inner">
                              <li>
                                  <a href="#" class="toggle notselected">Another nested element</a>
                                  <div class="inner">
                                      <p>
                                          As long as the inner element has inner as one of its classes then it will be toggled.
                                      </p>
                                      <p>
                                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
                                          blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
                                      </p>
                                  </div>
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>

                      <li>Option 2</li>

                      <li>Option 3</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
<script>

$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#'+div_id + ' > ul.' + current_level + ' li').siblings('a.selected:first').addClass('disabled');
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).removeClass("disabled");
  $(this).parent("li").siblings("li").children("a").addClass("disabled");
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="q2">
  <ul class="primary">
    <p class="question">Question 2.</p>
    <li>
      <a class="toggle notselected" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 3</a>
      <div class="inner" id="q2-1">
        <ul class="secondary">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="toggle notselected">Open Inner #1</a>
            <div class="inner">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
              </p>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#" class="toggle notselected">Open Inner #2</a>
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
              </p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="toggle notselected" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 4</a>
      <div class="inner" id="q2-2">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="toggle notselected">Technically any number of nested elements</a>
            <ul class="inner">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="toggle notselected">Another nested element</a>
                <div class="inner">
                  <p>
                    As long as the inner element has inner as one of its classes then it will be toggled.
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
                    blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>Option 2</li>

          <li>Option 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```